# What is the reason for redirecting the landing page of a site to a URL with '/#/' at the end?

Tags: reverse-proxy, rewrite, url

What is the reason for redirecting the landing page of a site to a URL with '/#/' at the end?

The system administrators at my company use a Apache reverse proxy, and they always redirect all the external websites to a landing page that ends with '/#/'.

For example:

```
https://example.com/springApp/#/
```

Is there any particular reason for this?   I am a technical person, but I can't think of a reason for this.  Just curious.  NOTE: our website does NOT use page scroll anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript [Single-page apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) often use a hash to handle navigation within the app (clicking on a link in the application might update the hash to `https://example.com/springApp/#/foo/bar`, for example). It's becoming less common as the HTML5 History API becomes well supported, though.

Comment: Ok, that may be the explanation as the applications use Ember.js